# Mongo server and openssl binary show different openssl versions

Tags: mongodb, ssl, openssl, centos, tls1.2

After installing mongodb on CentOS 7 I ran into an issue with openssl versions. Version installed on the system is 1.0.2k-fips whereas during mongod startup 1.0.1e-fips is printed. How exactly is this possible and is there any way to tell mongo server to use 1.0.2 version ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMbwt.png

Comment: This would mean that the MongoDB was compiled with OpenSSL linked in statically, and is an indirect sign that you have installed MongoDB via manual compilation as opposed to using packaged install. How did you install it?

Comment: I followed the instructions from mongo docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/
Created file in yum.repos.d and ran "yum install -y mongodb-org". Does that mean mongo comes with predefined, statically linked openssl version which cant be changed? Is there a mongo version that can run openssl 1.0.2 or somewhere I can check it ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a RHEL [peculiarity](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1462343).

MongoDB is linked dynamically against OpenSSL, and should use the system OpenSSL library. You can verify this by running

```
ldd `which openssl`
ldd `which mongod`
```

The two commands should show references to the system-wide `libssl` and `libcrypto`.

What I think happened is RedHat updated OpenSSL from 1.0.1e to 1.0.2k, but retained the "1.0.1e" label for compatibility purposes in parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

So indeed, MongoDB *is* using system OpenSSL library, which can be verified with `ldd`.

The issue with version misinformation is because since *a while ago* (RHEL 6.x releases), RedHat [changed `SSLeay()` function](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/6.9_release_notes/known_issues_security) to report *build* time version as opposed to the run-time:

> Because certain applications perform incorrect version check of the OpenSSL version, the actual runtime version of OpenSSL is masked and the build-time version is reported instead. Consequently, it is impossible to detect the currently running OpenSSL version using the SSLeay() function.

MongoDB uses this exact function to report OpenSSL version, [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.2.3/src/mongo/util/version.cpp#L188).

So when you use MongoDB packages and see `1.0.1e-fips` while the system OpenSSL version is `1.0.2k-fips`, this only means that the system where the package was built on had the older OpenSSL version, but the actual runtime version is your system one, `1.0.2k-fips`.

Comment: So I am actually trying to create mongodb + openssl docker container. First I copy mongod and mongo into /usr/bin. At this point I do not have openssl binary on my image yet mongo starts without errors (printing 1.0.1 as usual). If I then copy over openssl into /usr/bin I get mentioned versions mismatch.

If this is only SSLeay function issue, shouldn't mongo crash when openssl binary is not present ? Does it mean I do not need the binary at all or is it a bug and it will error later on when it actually would try to access it ? From what I understand binary defines system openssl version